# glsl.heroku.com code fails to run on Windows machines

Tags: glsl

http://glsl.heroku.com/e#7280.10

My cute glsl.heroku fractal runs fine on my Macbook Pro, but fails to run on all Windows machines/OSes that I've tried. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason in some environments global variable definitions get assigned more than once and your code was relying on that. I don't understand how that was working as every programming language I have used globals only get assigned 1 time. The funny thing is your original code also worked for my LG G2 Android phone too.

Move deltax, deltay, imag, and real float definitions into void main. Here is a link to the fix below.

http://glsl.heroku.com/e#11605.0